# Android phone won't connect to WiFi when Laptop off

Tags: wi-fi, router

A customer has a weird problem:

After he switches on his router/DSL-modem, his Android phone won't connect to WiFi. When he turns on his laptop (connected by LAN to the router), the phone suddenly is able to connect to WiFi.

When the laptop is subsequently turned off again, the phone stays connected to WiFi.

So, once the router is switched off and on again, WiFi only becomes available to the phone when the laptop is turned on (and then off).

Apparently this started to happen a week ago, without any changes in settings. I checked all his router settings remotely and all seems to be in order. He doesn't have TeamViewer on his phone, so I couldn't really check all its settings, but nothing is supposed to have changed.

Hence, all suggestions welcome.

Comment: That makes no sense at all... Default the router, connect and set it up again initially with no WiFI security turned on, then turn off the laptop. Go into the Android device and do a network reset (Settings - Backup & Reset - Network Settings Reset), and attempt to connect to the router. If successful, turn on WPA2, set the passcode and turn on AES only encryption and retest. And why is the router constantly being turned on and off again? It is best to leave it on 24/7

Comment: My thoughts exactly, what the sense is concerned. Since I'm 800 km from that customer, I'm postponing further action until I'm there, in order to avoid the risk of him locking everything up for all eternity. Thanks.

Comment: Install Vysor, and tell your customer to install also Vysor add-on on Google Chrome, then tell him how to send you remote control to his phone (you will get full access to the phone including adb and view his screen on your computer)